Strange extent making it impossible to clip to national boundary
I am using R to prepare different projections of gridded population data for a specific country. The dataset is global and can be found here: https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Projecting_1_km-grid_population_distributions_from_2020_to_2100_globally_under_shared_socioeconomic_pathways/19608594/2?file=36918880. Using the 2020 example, i get the following extent and crs:
extent(Global)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -0.4916667 
xmax       : 43199.51 
ymin       : -18719.5 
ymax       : 0.5 ```

crs(Global)
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
WKT2 2019 representation:
GEOGCRS["unknown",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ID["EPSG",6326]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8901]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]] .

I tried to change the extent to degrees (90 to -60 and 180 to -180). However this resulted in the equator and and 0 latitude being wrong, so when I clip for my area (in WGS84 projection) I am off.
I have tried to do this iteratively, but it is definitely the wrong approach. The only other relevant information is that the resolution should be 30 arcseconds.
Here is a summary of Global dataset for 2020 SSP1:
Global
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 18720, 43200, 808704000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -0.4916667, 43199.51, -18719.5, 0.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : SSP1_2020.tif 
names      : SSP1_2020 
values     : 0, 129371  (min, max)


It seems as soon as I wrote the question, I was able to come across the answer. So here it is:
The dataset was based on world population 30 arcsecond dataset (https://www.worldpop.org/about/). So downloaded one of the rasters and used the extent and resolution from that to create a blank raster and copy data through. This provides a more reasonable looking map and allows me to mask to my shapefile. Here is the r-code for reference:
   fix_raster_extent <- function(r) {
   # Set the correct extent and resolution
   new_extent <- extent(-180.0012, 179.9987, -71.99208, 84.00792)
   new_res <- c(0.008333333, 0.008333333)
   
   # Create a new raster with correct extent and resolution
   r_fixed <- raster(ext = new_extent, resolution = new_res, crs = wgs84)
   
   # Transfer values from the original raster
   values(r_fixed) <- values(r)
   
   return(r_fixed)}

